# C# How To Update Access Table From Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, updates

how  to update access table from excel?

```
 string Access = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\DB.mdb";
            string Excel = fileName;
            string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MS Access;Database=" + Access + "].[person] set vahedH=@vahedH,Bprice=@Bprice, Qest=@asd,mande=@mande,Date=@Date WHERE pcode=@pcode SELECT * FROM [result$]";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vahedH", "sts");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bprice", "sts");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asd", "sts");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mande", "sts");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", "sts");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", 1250);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
```

Invalid argument.
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to MSDN**

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

This means that instead of using named parameters as you did, you must replace the named parameters in your SQL statement with ?(for example the @vahedH should be just ?), and then add the parameters in the same order you want to insert them.

Your code would then be(changes only):

```
...    

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MS Access;Database=" + Access + "].[person] set vahedH=?,Bprice=?, Qest=?,mande=?,Date=? WHERE pcode=? SELECT * FROM [result$]";
...
```

You can then add the parameters the same way you just did, the parameter names will not matter though, only the order in which they are added.